# What do I do after killing Garnier de Naplouse?

Tags: assassins-creed

I'm on Memory Block 3, in Damascus for my first time, and I killed the doctor abusing his patients (and turning them into mental cases) in the castle. I returned to the guild, and now I have no objectives. What do I do?

Comment: Have you gone back to the Assassin's guild yet?

Comment: yes, i have been to the guild

Comment: Is this the first boss-fight assassination you've done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to head back to Masyaf now and speak to Mualim. You have to do this after nearly every assassination, except on the last missions in memory blocks, after which you return to the real world.